# Get into recovery mode on Xperia ray

Tags: recovery-mode, sony-xperia

I want to install a custom ROM in my Xperia ray. I have rooted my phone, unlocked the bootloader, and also installed ClockworkMod recovery. I have downloaded the custom ROM and Gapps on my SD card. But I am not able to enter recovery mode. I am always sent to safe mode.

I have tried the first two pages on google but had no success.

Please help.

Comment: Check your ClockworkMod recovery installation. Have you edited the permissions of CWM files once you've copied them into the system?

Answer (score 0):

Download Android Studio, install ADB SDK, then open command prompt, change directory to

```
C:\Users\[UserName]\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools
```

Then hit the following in command prompt

```
adb reboot recovery
```

Then your phone enters recovery mode. I did the same in my Xperia Ray and succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

**TWRP recovery with modified kernel**
I was unable to boot into recovery mode, when trying to root my Sony Xperia Z5 for the first time.

It worked after modifying my Android 7 Nougat kernel with this tool: https://forum.xda-developers.com/xperia-z5/development/root-automatic-repack-stock-kernel-dm-t3301605

After that I had to but also could enter recovery mode via "adb reboot recovery". Which then worked well for me.

Trying to install lineageos... .zip, the check for right device was wrong in my case.

```
Installing zip file '... .zip'
Checking for MD5 file...
Skipping MD5 check: no MD5 file found
E3004: This package is for device: E6633,E6653,sumire,sumire_dsds; this device is .

E:unknown command [log]
Updater process ended with ERROR: 7
Error installing zip file '....zip'
Updating partition details
```

It can be changed easily as desribed here:
https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2522762

Worked well for me.